# Catch external jar stop event for Spring-boot application with Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

to launch my Spring Boot application in production environment my company has a system that executes "java -jar" and I'm trying to simultate it in my Intellij idea and jar starts correctly and I can debug with proyect source too.

In run and debug mode, when I click in stop button the jar is stopped suddenly with the message:

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58575', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

And I can´t catch the close event to close my DB connections. I've tryed other stackoverflow solutions like [PortalServiceLifeCycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853148/catch-application-stop-event-for-spring-boot-application), [@PreDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585350/does-spring-have-a-shutdown-process-to-put-cleanup-code) and [setRegisterShutdownHook(false) in SpringApplication run in main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812822/prevent-database-shutdown-command-from-spring-boot).

Jar is created by Maven with clean and package goals and we haven't xml spring configurations, only annotations.

What I need to catch shutdown service to close connections?

Edit: Add my Intellij buttons:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727696/104891).

This feature is [not available](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171093) in Debug mode yet.

This feature is also not available for **JAR** run configuration, but is available for **Application** run configuration.

You can use remote debug and Ctrl+C in the external console to debug the code in the shutdown hooks until [IDEA-171093](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171093) is implemented.

Comment: For these answer I haven´t this button in my 2018 version.

Comment: That is correct, this button is available only in Run mode when IDE agent is loaded. It's not available in Debug mode and in certain run configuration types.

Comment: Hi, I've added my Intellij buttons in the original post. What is the button to exit?

Comment: This feature is not available for JAR Run configuration, but is available for Application Run configuration.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available for Gradle run tasks either